# Max Height for a dynamically sized WPF Textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

I'd like to make a TextBox in XAML that is dynamically sized to the content, but that has a max height that keeps it from growing forever if that text is very long. If that max height is reached, the TextBox should stop growing and instead show a scroll bar. Ideally, that scrollbar does not exist when the text fits. How would I go about that?

I gain the dynamic resizing property by simply not setting an explicit Height on the TextBox (and possibly turning on text wrapping). But achieving the max height and scroll bar is a mystery to me.

Currently  I have a setup that always shows a scroll bar and that grows forever. How would I change this?

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Selection.SummeryDescription, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Hace you tried setting `TextBox.MaxHeight` and `ScrollViewer.MaxHeight`?

Comment: Setting a MaxHeight for the ScrollViewer does the trick for restricting size, didn't know that property existed. But the scroll bar is still there at all times, instead of only when needed.

Comment: You can avoid the scroll bar when it is not needed. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that just by setting the ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Auto and the MaxHeight. See example below:

```
<TextBox Text="..." TextWrapping="Wrap" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="500" />
```

This will only show a vertical scrollbar when needed.

Please notice that in my example the ScrollViewer element is omitted as I enable the ScrollViewer via the ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility property instead.